# Ignore data until e-mail is found?

Tags: regex

In the following text...

```
^here there me@acme.com$
```

... I'd like to ignore and remove all the data before the e-mail address so that I end up with just the e-mail.

I used the following regex, but it simply prepends a `@`:

```
^([^ ].+?@.+)$
```

I thought the syntax `[^ ].+?` meant: "*one or more non-space characters*", but it doesn't do what I expected.

---

There are cases where, for some reason, the regexes `[^ ]+@.+$` or `^[^ ]+@.+$` take both lines:

```
SomeWord
me@acme.com
```

Comment: To answer your edit, `[^ ]+@.+$` matches that because newlines are not spaces. See edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^ ].+?` Really means "one non-espace character (`h`), followed by an arbitrary by a group of characters. (`ere there me`)"

Try this instead:

```
\S+@.+$
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrongly prepented the pattern with "^", and removing it solved the issue.

Comment: Er... It mostly works, but I happened upon a few lines that don't work as expected. Edited to show what it does.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*@[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*
```

(Can be tweaked as needed)

Comment: Read: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx